# can a upnp device send actions to a control point in an upnp network?

Tags: upnp

I know control point can send actions to a upnp device using UpnpSendActionAsync() function, but I wonder whether I can send actions to the control point by a way similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, unless the control point also publishes a UPnP device and service.

If you explain what you are trying to do, I could offer some other advice but I think that is a comprehensive answer to the current question.

Comment: I am using a music software in my cellphone to push music to a development board using dlna.And I want to control to play next/last song by the means of using the board to send message to the music software.I am sorry to trouble you.